# Talend ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, talend

How can I run/execute a job talend from an application ASP.NET MVC ?
I have e job which is created with talend: this job migrate data from one database to another .I wish to deploy this job in application asp.net mvc.
Any idea about this?

Comment: can you run commandline batch file .bat or similar from asp.net mvc? if yes, then you can export talend job as batch job and run it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend exposing your Talend job as a web service from within the TAC.  Once deployed, you can use standard techniques (client or server side) to call the web service.

Here is a link to Talend's documentation on the subject:
https://help.talend.com/display/KB/Deploying+or+exposing+a+Job+as+a+Web+service

Answer (score 0):

can you run commandline batch file .bat or similar from asp.net mvc? if yes, then you can export talend job as batch job and run it

Comment: I'm quite sure that normally you are not allowed to do this from an IIS web application with the standard IIS user.

Answer (score 0):

Granting file system level access to a web application is always risky business : ) But happens sometimes. Here's what you will need

1. A separate technical user - either local or AD - that has proper access to the folder where you store the exported Talend job. I'm kind of unsure about the proper access, first because a compiled java job is not really same as an EXE, only executed by java, second because it might also depend on what you do in the job. But it can be clarified with a few tries, start with read + write. (Technically you could do this with the user IIS runs your web site with, but that's less secure.)
2. Search for explanation or code samples of Impersonation (I'll provide one too). You use impersonation to change the environment your code is running in, from the IIS user to the technical user above. Because what you are allowed to do in the code is depending on who the user is.
3. Implement a program flow something like this: impersonate the technical user --> execute the talend job by calling the batch generated by Talend --> undo the impersonation.

System calls:

```
#region accountManagement

[DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
public static extern int LogonUserA(String lpszUserName, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int DuplicateToken(IntPtr hToken, int impersonationLevel, ref IntPtr hNewToken);
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool RevertToSelf();
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext;

private bool impersonateValidUser(String userName, String domain, String password)
{
    const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
    const int LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK = 3;
    const int LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH = 4;
    const int LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE = 5;
    const int LOGON32_LOGON_UNLOCK = 7;
    const int LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT = 8;
    const int LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 9;
    const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;

    WindowsIdentity tempWindowsIdentity;
    IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;

    if (RevertToSelf())
    {
        // Int32 result = LogonUserA(userName, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token);
        // Response.Write(">>> " + result.ToString());
        if (LogonUserA(userName, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token) != 0)
        {
            if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
            {
                tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
                impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
                if (impersonationContext != null)
                {
                    CloseHandle(token);
                    CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
        CloseHandle(token);
    if (tokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero)
        CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
    return false;
}

private void undoImpersonation()
{
    impersonationContext.Undo();
}

#endregion
```

And what you will have to implement yourself:

```
            String iuUser = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["domain.accountop.user"];
            String iuPass = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["domain.accountop.pass"];
            String iuDomn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["domain.name"];
            if (impersonateValidUser(iuUser, iuDomn, iuPass))
            {
                try
                {
                    // Execute your job here
                    ...
                    // finally: undo impersonation
                    undoImpersonation();
                    // maybe inform the user that it was successful
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Exception innerException = ex.InnerException;
                    // give some nice error message here, make a log entry, etc
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // The impersonation failed. Include a fail-safe mechanism here.
                // number of possible errors will get you here: wrong or expired password, user does not have a privilege to start an interactive session, etc.
            }
```